# Next JS Babel can't resolve 'module'

Tags: next.js, babeljs, linguijs

I've started to develop a multi-language web application with Next JS and Lingui.js
Lingui.js is using babel so I had to install it aswell.

I've followed this tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-internationalization-nextjs/
After facing some issues i've also followed the official documentation of Lingui.js https://lingui.js.org/tutorials/setup-react.html

I faced a lot of issues with babel and typescript.
But now I struggle with following error, which I could not find any help with:

```
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
error - ./node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/import-fresh/index.js
./node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
./node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js
./node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js
./node_modules/@lingui/macro/index.js
./src/pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
false
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/index.tsx:36:51)
    at I18nProvider (C:\Project\app\node_modules\@lingui\react\cjs\react.development.js:46:19)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:48:24)
    at StyleRegistry (C:\Project\app\node_modules\styled-jsx\dist\index\index.js:671:34)
    at AppContainer (C:\Project\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:394:29)
    at AppContainerWithIsomorphicFiberStructure (C:\Project\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:424:57)
    at div
    at Body (C:\Project\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:701:21)
error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "regenerator": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
            {
                "runtime": "automatic"
            }
        ],
        [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
                absoluteRuntime: false,
                corejs: false,
                helpers: true,
                regenerator: true,
                version: '7.0.0-beta.0',
            },
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
        ],
    ]
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

The part with React.jsx: type is invalid is because of getStaticProps in index.tsx.

So this might be an separate issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/azu/rc-config-loader/issues/2#issuecomment-442032866) ?

*webpack.config.js*

```
 node: {
 module: "empty",
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up deleting everything I had from Babel and lingui and copied all imports from another project which was running.

Cannot name the difference between them, but it worked afterwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).